# Why I am getting null pointer exception in the following code?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my code, I am getting NPE in function writeFile(). The point is passing a String to writeFile() method which then creates a file using createFile() and writing the String to newly created file.

The file is created in successfully in directory, but nothing is being written to it.
The String shows output at Logcat too, so its clear it is not an empty string.

```
public File createFile( ){
    File storageLocation = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path);
    storageLocation.mkdirs();
    if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot use storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    try{
         File file = new File(storageLocation, getFileName()+".xml");
         file.createNewFile();
    }
    catch( IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return file;
}

public String getFileName( ){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyy",Locale.UK);
    return sdf.format(c.getTime( ));
}

 public void writeFile( String text ){
     try{
line 56>>   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( createFile( ).getAbsoluteFile());
            out = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeUTF(text);
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            out.close();
     }
     catch( IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }
     catch( NullPointerException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }
 }
```

Edit : 
Permissions are set as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is log from Logcat :

```
05-04 09:21:47.276: W/System.err(1137): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 09:21:47.286: W/System.err(1137):     at com.codepalette.ceeq.FileManager.writeFile(FileManager.java:56)
05-04 09:21:47.286: W/System.err(1137):     at  com.codepalette.ceeq.BackupManager.backCallLogs(BackupManager.java:50)
05-04 09:21:47.286: W/System.err(1137):     at com.codepalette.ceeq.BackupManager.takeBackup(BackupManager.java:25)
05-04 09:21:47.296: W/System.err(1137):     at com.codepalette.ceeq.Home$2.onClick(Home.java:154)
```

Comment: where is the line number FileManager.java:56

Comment: that is first line after try block in writeFile() function.

Comment: when I asked which line I meant that you should edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: this is not even a compiling code dude... `File file` scope ends in the try block, how are you returning the file object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in your code and I doubt that you can run it.
The variable file (File) cannot be returned as it is declared, it's out of scope.

try change it like this:

```
try {
     File file = new File(storageLocation, getFileName()+".xml");
     file.createNewFile();
     return file;
}
catch( IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Comment: Eclipse gives error when i am returning it from try block. :)
Wait a second, I give it a try too.

Comment: That is the point .. returning the result from try block and returning null from the function .. !

Comment: This code wont compile, check and see, I am sure you are running a older build and line 56 is something else.

Comment: Siddarth Sir, it did ! but it gave error in other function ! Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the relevant permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in the manifest file, to write to external storage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the calender object that you used in getFileName()?

Comment: yup ! :) 
 in the constructor itself .. !
     `public FileManager( Context context ){
  this.context = context;
  c = Calendar.getInstance();`
 }